# Sorting a datetime list in Robot framework

Tags: python, sorting, testing, robotframework

I'm trying to sort a list of datetime elements. First, I am looping through a table column to extract the dates within each row of the column. Due to the fact that these are pulled as a string, I am then converting them in to dates. The aim is to extract the dates that were sorted on the page, then add these dates to a list, sort the dates within Robot and ensure that the two lists are the same. The issue is that there does not seem to be a simple way to sort datetime in Robot. I have tried using Sort List, but this retrieves a null value, and also tried using sorted() function but this receives and error message:
'SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers'.

The formate of the dates appear like so - '07/10/2023 06:10:35 AM', if this helps.

Please help :)

My code is as follows:

```
   [Documentation]   Table is successfully sorted from newest to oldest
       # Select the column elements using XPath
    ${column_elements}    Browser.Get Elements    xpath=//table//td[7]

    # Extract values from the column elements
    ${dates}=    Create List
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    0    ${column_elements.__len__()}
        ${element}=    Get From List    ${column_elements}    ${index}
        ${value}=    Get Text    ${element}
        Append To List    ${dates}    ${value}
    END

    # Sort the dates in descending order (newest to oldest)
    FOR  ${date}  IN  @{dates}
        ${converted_date}  Convert Date  ${date}  result_format=%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p    date_format=%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p
        Log  Converted date: ${converted_date}
    END
    ${sorted_dates}=    Evaluate    sorted(${converted_date})


    # Verify that the table is sorted correctly
    Lists Should Be Equal    ${dates}    ${sorted_dates}

    # Log the extracted values
    Log    Column Values: ${dates}
```